# Handling Server FIN Packets in Locust

Tags: locust

How does Locust handle cases where the server sends a FIN packet to the client (user)?
Considering the given scenario, if the client-server connection has already been established and the server has a KeepAliveTimeout of 5 seconds, while the client has a think-time of 10 seconds, the server will close the client's connection by sending a TCP FIN packet due to no request from the client within those 5 seconds. In this situation, will the client been terminated by locust?

I'm expecting a termination and not recreation of that user

Comment: Locusts HttpUser's `self.client` is a python-requests Session: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects 

Please consult its documentation. It doesnt really provide much control over TCP level stuff I'm afraid.